# Can't paste into web form

Tags: asp.net, html, clipboard

A user complains they can't paste into one particular text box on a form and that this is a change in behavior that occurred three months ago. I can't reproduce the error. I've tried long text, short text, plain text, formatted text, everything works. I did fix some poorly formatted HTML, but it didn't change their problem.

The user and I are both using XP/IE7. The application uses a proprietary MVC framework with C# on .NET 1.1. The UI only works reliably in IE. (I tried Opera and the paste works, I can't get logged in with Firefox to get to the screen.)

Any ideas where to start?

Thanks!

Edit - here's dialog I had with the user that didn't bring to light any issues.

> You were actually on the right track
>   in asking about the firewall, because
>   you are trying to identify something
>   that is different between me and you.
>   Here's some other potential
>   differences.
>
> Maybe we aren't doing it the same way:
>   Do you use keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl-C,
>   Ctrl V) or the context menu (right
>   mouse click and select copy/paste)?
>
> Maybe our computers are different:
>   What hardware (Windows/Mac), operating
>   system (XP, Vista, etc.), and browser
>   (IE, Firefox, etc.) are you using?
>
> Maybe our understanding of the problem
>   is different: Do you not see the text
>   when you paste it in, or is it not
>   being saved?
>
> Maybe what we are copying from is
>   different: I copied something from
>   Bugzilla and something from notepad.
>   Both are plain text. I need to try
>   formatted text, like from a PDF and
>   from Word. You need to try plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be actually a user training issue. If it were me, I'd use something like [crossloop](http://www.crossloop.com) to watch the user interact with the page. If you can see what they are actually doing (not what they SAY they are doing) then you have half a chance at reproduction of the issue. Based on your description, it is very likely not an issue with the software, but a [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC) situation with your user.

### Notes on Crossloop

We use crossloop with our clients and our developers in training. Basically you install the software (very easy) on both your computer and the end user's computer. The end user then authorizes you to "see" his machine by sending you a connection code. Once connected, both you and the user can move the mouse/type/see the other person use the mouse.

It would be like a remote desktop or vnc session, but much easier to get up and running across firewalls and without too much setup/config headache.

**It is also a free download, and a free service** (the last time i used it anyway).

### Suggested course of action

1. Install Crossloop on your machine and familiarize yourself with it. (maybe do a trial run connect with a co-worker)
2. Call user and ask if they would be willing to show their issue to you directly via some screen sharing software.
3. Walk them through the install and connect of Crossloop.
4. Instruct them to show you the issue.
5. Watch for glaring errors, etc.
6. Hopefully see either what the user is doing wrong, or what conditions the bug manifests itself.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like a promising tool.

Comment: WebEx is another alternative.  If you have an account you can give the guest presenter satus and they can share their desktop.

Comment: I have used webex, vnc, and cisco's meeting place. Any of these would work, but crossloop is particularly easy to get up and running: Download, install, run, connect.